# How to remove (not change) erroneous application default in Windows 11 and leave with no default?

Tags: windows-11

I accidentally assigned a default application to the file type **.bak** in Windows 11.  (It's used as for backup copies in several applications, so I don't want it associated with *any* application at all.)

Is there a way to just **remove** the association?

I tried resetting all default applications but that didn't clear it.  (This is a new system so I didn't lose much customization.)

I am able to change the default, but I really don't want any application to try and open .bak files by default.

Comment: Unfortunately. so far as I know, you cannot replace an existing association with nothing.  No provision for that.  At least not in native Windows.

Comment: You just delete the file assoication registry key for thst specific file extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HOW TO CLEAR FILE ASSOCIATION**

From admin command prompt (in Start/Search type: "cmd.exe" and choose to run it as Admin) enter this command, leaving nothing after the equal (=) sign:

```
assoc .ext=
```

where **.ext** is the extension you want to remove (e.g. ".sav"), reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc

You may also want to remove the open command for the associated app with that extension... reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype

Finally... to remove the "bad_program.exe" from the list of suggested default apps when you'll associate new file types in the future, find in the registry ("RegEdit" command from an Admin prompt) the app key, e.g.:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\bad_program.exe
```

and with right mouse button add a new *String value*: "NoOpenWith", (the *bad_program.exe* in this example pic is "winhlp32.exe") e.g.:
[image: NoOpenWith value added to hide a program from the list of suggested default apps]

Now that app won't be listed anymore in the suggested programs list for a new file type association.

Comment: The **assoc** command appears to have worked. (Though I haven't tried the registry edits.)  The icons for .bak files still look like the erroneous application, but that's a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open `regedit.exe` elevated (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, type "regedit", hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while right-clicking or <kbd>Context Menu</kbd>, select "Run as Administrator").

To be safe, you can take a backup prior to making any registry changes.  When ready, navigate to and delete the incorrect key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\<file type>\UserChoice`

Comment: I found `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bak` in the registry, but it has no `UserChoice` key.

Comment: In that case, try Local Computer rather than Current User.

Comment: @arctic I checked under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\` and there is no FileExts key.

Comment: When you navigate to ```Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\\```, what do you see?  Do you see a list of file extensions "directories"?  When going to `.bak`, what "subdirectories" are stored there?  For **each extension type** you should see something like `OpenWithList`, `OpenWithProgIDs`, and — if you selected an "open with" default through the userspace before — `UserChoice`.  Just delete that entire key.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, there was no `UserChoice` key. I tried assigning a different app through Default Apps, which created a key pointing to the new application.  I deleted the key, and it reverted to the original erroneous app!

Comment: At this point, speaking in the interest of solving your personal inquiry, if I were in your shoes I would look into a) the mechanics on the backend that determine the default application selection criteria, b) the viability of adapting this process in reverse, i.e., creating a new default application selection behavior by the addition of a key value in the registry, and finally c) the appropriate attributes necessary for a registry key value to (functionally speaking) render a "null" action (so to speak).  While not to the letter of your question, this might at least fulfill the spirit of it?